# Raster CRS projection inconsistency in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I have a number of satellite images covering Greece - downloaded from USGS: Earth Explorer "Landsat-Collection 2-Level1" collection.

The one group of images has a default CRS projection 'EPSG:32634' and the other group has 'EPSG:32635'.

My project has a third projection 'EPSG:2100'.

In my map view, all images appear properly (no gaps, no transpositions, no overlays), however I cannot merge them properly, since a single projection has to be applied.

I tried every possible combination of projections, reprojections, etc, but the images do not appear properly, although they can be merged.

I want to load them from scratch in a new project with a single projection for every layer, what should I do?

[image: Loaded rasters and CRS]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: If they draw correctly in a project-on-the-fly map canvas, then you just need to reproject correctly. Never "Define Projection" on a functional dataset, only "Project". Detail your exact procedure for only one dataset.

Comment: I set the project crs in EPSG:2100
In settings I have a default projection for the project (EPSG:2100) and unknown layers setting is to leave as an unknown crs
I loaded all images, half of them had EPSG:32634 by default and the others had the EPSG:32635. The map appeared as it should.
I tried to set crs from properties for all layers that differed to EPSG:32634, failed
I also changed the project crs to EPSG:32634, failed
I repeated the process for the EPSG:32635, failed.
I tried the function setCrs() from python console, failed
I tried with assign, extract and warp from toolbar, failed.

Comment: "Setting a projection" != "reprojecting". The layer properties have a big bold warning about overriding the CRS. What made you think that this was the right place to reproject your data? Honest question so we can improve QGIS.

Comment: @bugmenot123 I knew that this was not the right way. However, after I tested the reprojection tools (warp) and failed, I had to try out every desperate solution. Still, can't figure a way out of it. Any suggestions? Any solutions? 
My guess is that QGIS has made some reprojecting over-fly and despite that my images have different projections, it appears to be correct. Perhaps, the only way out is to try ArcGIS...

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure that your layers all have their actual CRS correctly assigned. If your layers all align nicely in your QGIS project's map canvas and if you can see them in the right location when compared to a layer that is definitely correct (for example the OpenStreetMap XYZ tile layer) then proceed.
2. Choose an appropriate common CRS, in your case probably EPSG:2100 or one of the UTM zones.
3. For each raster that is not natively in that CRS either right-click & "Export" & "Save as..." or use the top menu to "Raster" & "Projections" & "Warp (Reproject)", choose the common CRS as target.
4. Create a new project and load all the already-in-the-CRS files plus the reprojected files.

Comment: @OP: "Make sure that your layers all have their actual CRS correctly assigned" set a basemap in the background to see if that is the case. **Always** do that!

Comment: Great point, I added that.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Thank you for your suggestions. This is the process I usually follow. Unfortunately, the main problem I noticed mostly in QGIS is that if you have a project crs (suppose EPSG:2100) and have all your layers in that project, there are some rasters that cannot be properly transformed. However, by changing the projection according to the crs of the "problematic rasters", the problem seems to be solved - although all other layers have to be also reprojected - a task that is not always successful or useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I finally realised that the most easy way out of this problem (not exactly a solution) is to work with ArcGIS when this kind of issue arises. I tried all the possible solutions I could imagine alongside with the ones posted in the answers. However, a **wrong step** in the whole procedure when **using QGIS might ruin a layer's crs forever**! 
It seems that QGIS did a "shallow" assignment of a crs without reprojecting the actual pixels of the raster, meaning that all layers will apear properly, however not a single routine combining all these layers together can be applied because they have a different projection in their properties but their pixels refer to the same crs (perhaps because I had not paid attention to the '**layers crs setting**' when I first loaded them)
**Important** From the experience I had, pay attention to the following in similar cases when using QGIS:
1] Backup all the layers that don't appear properly in their original crs (even if there is not a crs at all) 
2] Open a new project and select in 'Crs for project' -> use a default crs.
Select the crs you want for your project (commonly the one that the majority of your layers refer to)
3] Set the 'Default crs for layers' as in step 2] 
**4] In the section 'when a new layer is created, or when a layer is loaded and has no crs' -> Leave as an unknown crs (take no action)** 
5] Load your layers. Don't take any action if any prompt or notification appears. You might want to check your layers if they align with a layer that is definitely correct (as the OpenStreetMap XYZ tile layer)
6] Save your project, as QGIS is likely to crash in the following procedure.
7] If the layers don't appear aligned, have a look in the layer properties section, find the crs of the layers and write it down [or grab the active layer in the python console with a command like: 'layer = iface.activeLayer()' and then layer.crs()]
8] Note which layers - from those that don't appear properly - have a crs that differs from the project crs. **Don't do anything on the layers that have the same crs as the project.**
9] Try to reproject the layer[s] that have a different crs from the project, by using the 'Warp (reproject)' tool from raster -> projection. Select the crs of the project.
10] If step 9] fails, delete the Warp output and change the crs of the layer[s] that do not align from the layer properties or via python command [crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:2100') 
 layer.setCrs(crs) 
 Replace EPSG:2100 with yours]
11] If step 10] fails, you should probably try a similar routine in ArcGIS, which might save you some time. **Do not combine steps 9] and 10]!**